# Software/tool to generate R-G-B values of every pixel from an image and vice-versa

Tags: image-processing

Is there a software/tool that can generate me a matrix of RGB values from a simple raw 8-bit RGB image?
Also, is there a software/tool that can generate an image from a given matrix of RGB values?

Thank you.

PS:

i) I am aware that this can be done using Matlab. I am looking for a tool that can do it that is not Matlab.

ii) I am aware of existing question about doing similar stuff programmatically. I need a software tool, if there is any, that can do this task.

Comment: Isn't matlab a "software tool"?

Comment: I do not have access to Matlab. So, looking for a software or web-application that can do this task.

Comment: Would Python, Matplotlib and PIL (Pillow) work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you use the venerable **NetPBM** which is available for Linux, macOS and Windows. Alternatively, you could use **ImageMagick** but that is much heavier weight, see later.

---

**NetPBM Method** - see [Wikipedia NetPBM entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format)

So, let's start with a raw, 8-bit RGB file that contains a red, a green and a blue pixel:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 mark  staff  9 10 Oct 07:47 rgb888.bin
```

As you can see, it has 9 bytes. Let's look at them:

```
xxd -g3 rgb888.bin

00000000: ff0000 00ff00 0000ff
```

Now, if we want that image as a matrix of legible values:

```
rawtoppm -plain 3 1 rgb888.bin
```

**Sample Output**

```
P3
3 1
255
255 0 0  0 255 0  0 0 255
```

where:

- `-plain` means to display in ASCII rather than binary
- P3 tells us it is colour and ASCII
- 3 1 tells us its dimension are 3 pixels wide by 1 pixel high
- 255 essentially tells us it is 8-bit (65536 would mean 16-bit)
- the last row is the pixels

Converting back to binary is a little harder, let's assume we start with a PPM file created like this:

```
rawtoppm -plain 3 1 rgb888.bin > image.ppm
```

So, we can get the binary version like this:

```
ppmtoppm < image.ppm | tail -c 9 > rgb888.bin
```

and look at it with:

```
xxd -g3 rgb888.bin
00000000: ff00 0000 ff00 0000 ff
```

---

**ImageMagick Method**

```
# Convert binary RGB888 to text
convert -depth 8 -size 3x1 RGB:rgb888.bin txt:
```

**Sample Output**

```
# ImageMagick pixel enumeration: 3,1,65535,srgb
0,0: (65535,0,0)  #FF0000  red
1,0: (0,65535,0)  #00FF00  lime
2,0: (0,0,65535)  #0000FF  blue
```

Or, slightly different appearance:

```
# Convert binary RGB888 to matrix
convert -depth 8 -size 3x1 RGB:rgb888.bin -compress none ppm:
```

**Sample Output**

```
P3
3 1
255
255 0 0 0 255 0 0 0 255
```

And now going the other way, PPM to binary

```
# Convert PPM image to binary
convert image.ppm rgb:image.bin

# Check how the binary looks
xxd -g 3 image.bin
00000000: ff0000 00ff00 0000ff                   .........
```

---

**Plain dump method**

Maybe you are happy with a plain dump from `od`:

```
od -An -t u1 rgb888.bin
```

**Sample Output**

```
255   0   0   0 255   0   0   0 255
```

Comment: Thanks Mark! NetPBM was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks again.